# Remove PHPGrid default message

Tags: phpgrid

I am using the free version of PHP Grid - Lite.
I have successfully integrated and the tool shows reports as exactly required.

The only problem is it shows a default text

```
"You are using phpGrid Lite. Please consider upgrading phpGrid to the full version to have great features including edit, master detail, and grouping, composite key, file upload, and premium themes!"
```

Is there a way I can disable it ?

Have also attached a sample image of it.
[Report View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAr9O.png)

Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps you could upgrade?  If you think about the amount of time you saved by using the product, it is usually extremely cost-effective to buy a license.

Answer (score 0):

The div which holds this text belongs to a class named

> 'pg_notify'

therefore writing a CSS for this class as follows could remove (make invisible) this text.

```
.pg_notify{
    display: none;
}
```

**OR** you could use PHP to change the CSS of the div containing this text you want to remove.

```
<?php 
echo '<style type = "text/css">
    .pg_notify{
            display: none;
       }
    </style>';
?>
```